# iOS - UITableView: TableVIew's backgroundColor during rotation/viewWillDisappear in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UITableView (MasterViewController of a UISplitViewController), whose
 `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`
 When the device rotates from landscape to portrait, i change it back to white using `backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]`, in it's `viewWillDisappear:` method. 
 But it does not change the color, until the next time the view appears. Therefore, i see a black background, as the tableViewDisappears, which is jarring.
 Is there a way to make the change appear immediately?

**Edit:-**
This is how to recreate the fault:
In a UISplitViewController based application's MasterViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //the color changes, only the next time the tableView appears.
}
```

Comment: `backgroundView = [UIColor whiteColor]` Don't you mean `backgroundColor` ?

Comment: Are you sure `viewWillDisappear` is called?

Comment: @AlexPeda Yes. It is called. Verified it with an `NSLog` statement. Also, the changes made in the `viewWillDisappear` method is reflected the next time the table view appears.